# How to convert color grain image to black and white (0,1) so that grain boundary remain identifiable

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, voronoi

I want to convert color image to binary image (0,1) using simple code `im2bw()`.

[image]

But in this case grain boundaries are lost or not properly visible

[image]

I would like to design grain boundary like

[image].

Any matlab or python explanation is highly acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB has a function [`boundarymask`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/boundarymask.html) that does what you want.

If the input image `lab` is a labeled image, then simply do `bw=boundarymask(lab)`.

If the input image is RGB, then you can do something like this:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUFSq.png'); % color image from question
bw = boundarymask(img(:,:,1)); % pretend the red channel is a labeled image.
```

Note that two regions might have the same value of red, and a boundary would not be drawn. To prevent this, element-wise OR together the results on each of the 3 channels:

```
bw = boundarymask(img(:,:,1));
bw = bw | boundarymask(img(:,:,2));
bw = bw | boundarymask(img(:,:,3));
```

Comment: Tried but not working, an error occur "Undefined function 'boundarymask' for input arguments of type 'uint8".

Comment: @amitava That requires MATLAB ≥ R2016a with Image Processing Toolbox. Check if you have that.